# How to implement a simple Subtractable type class

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I want to make a type class for subtractable types such that

- The value type implements `Ord`.
- There is a `subtract` function.
- It supports `UTCTime`, `Double`, and `Int` (or optionally any `Num` type)
- there is a `Delta` type which may differ from the source value type. For example, with a value type of `UTCTime`, the delta type is `NominalDiffTime`. For `Int`, `Double`, the delta type would be the same as the value type.

  diffUTCTime :: UTCTime -> UTCTime -> NominalDiffTime
- The delta type should implement `Num`.

This doesn't work at all but hopefully communicates what I'm trying to do

```
class Ord a => Subtractable a where
   -- The type alias for the delta type
   type Num b => b
   -- The subtract function
   subtractValues :: a -> a -> b
```

Comment: This already exists by the way: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.10.2/docs/Data-AffineSpace.html

Comment: the vector-space package and AffineSpace class is doing exactly what I wanted. I'm using that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with [type families](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families):

```
class Subtractable a where
  type Diff a :: *
  subtractValues :: a -> a -> Diff a
```

in your example for `UTCTime` this would be:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
module Stackoverflow where
import Data.Time.Clock

class Subtractable a where
  type Diff a :: *
  subtractValues :: a -> a -> Diff a

instance Subtractable UTCTime where
  type Diff UTCTime = NominalDiffTime
  subtractValues = diffUTCTime
```

and yield something like this:

```
λ> t1 <- getCurrentTime
λ> t2 <- getCurrentTime
λ> subtractValues t2 t1
5.327944s
```

(as you can see I am quite slow at typing ;) )

you can add the constraint on `Num` if you add `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}` and change the `class` to:

```
class (Num (Diff a)) => Subtractable a where
  type Diff a :: *
  subtractValues :: a -> a -> Diff a
```

---

### instance for `Int`

```
instance Subtractable Int where
  type Diff Int = Int
  subtractValues = (-)
```

---

### using `MultiParamTypeClasses` and `FunctionalDependencies`

you can also do this with multiparam-type-classes and [functional dependencies](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies) but I prefer the *type families* approach - but this is obviously my opinion

Anyway here is a version using FDs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
module StackOverflow where
import Data.Time.Clock

class Num b => Subtractable a b | a -> b where
  subtractValues :: a -> a -> b

instance Subtractable UTCTime NominalDiffTime where
  subtractValues = diffUTCTime
```

---

#### remarks

- just saw that I should have put `Delta` instead of `Diff` - I think you get it
- if you try to do this for general `Num a` you will run into really nasty stuff (the compiler will not be able to decide which `Diff a` to choose basically) - so right now I see no way to make this work ATM but there are probably people around that can come up with a *trick* (or tell me where I miss the point completely ;) )

Comment: Wow, this is perfect, except, I need to add a Num constraint to the Diff type. Is that possible?

Comment: oops ... I just mentioned that the constraint is not working as intended - sorry for that (I think in this case it's indeed better to go with functional deps - I'll reedit ... one moment)

Comment: The Num constraint should go on the (Diff a) in the first line of the class declaration. Also add basic (Ord a) constraint. Thanks!!!

Comment: because there is no instance for numbers (yet) - you should try to add it - it should be quite simple

Comment: I added an Int instance and subtractValues doesn't work.

Comment: I added an instance for `Int`

Comment: That Int instance is what I had. Is `subtractValues 5 3` working for you? For me it is not.

Comment: also note that you have to *help out* the compiler with the `Num` as this: ` subtractValues (5 :: Int) 3` if you try it (see `5` can be lot's of things)

Comment: Can you define an instance for any type that implements Num?

Comment: I don't think so - but maybe a **wizzard** will show up and proof me wrong

Comment: @clay, no, a "superclass instance" (i.e. an instance for every type that implements `Num`) is not possible except for when it is the only instance.  It's too bad -- if we allowed it though, the existence of orphan instances could break things really subtly and hard-to-fixly.

Comment: @luqui thanks for the clarification - do you know any good reference material on this issue? Right now it's most often "throw it at GHC and see if it complains" for me and I would love to get a better feeling and possible even *acutal knowledge* of  why and when things like this work.

Comment: @Carsten, Writing your own typechecker is extremely educational for building and intuition for the kinds of trade-offs that are involved.  It's heavier than reading, but worth it.

Comment: @luqui ^^ ... maybe this is really a good idea (for a moment I feared you would point me to HoTT) - of course this might take me a few years (turns out that you cannot do meaningful stuff in the evening any more if you are getting old ... you just want your f'ing sleep)

Answer (score 3):

You want [the `AffineSpace` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.10.2/docs/Data-AffineSpace.html).

```
class AdditiveGroup (Diff p) => AffineSpace p where
  type Diff p
  (.-.) :: p -> p -> Diff p
  (.+^) :: p -> Diff p -> p

instance AffineSpace UTCTime where
  type Diff UTCTime = NominalDiffTime
  (.-.) = diffUTCTime
  (.+^) = flip addUTCTime
```

Comment: Thank you. The vector-space package and AffineSpace class is doing exactly what I wanted. I'm using that.